# Mod_wsgi_express: Image is not loading in the browser

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I installed the `mod_wsgi-express` (Into the python), everything is working fine.
But, when i tried to send some pics on browser, it's not running, Firebug says - `Failed to load the given URL`.

Below is my wsgi configuration under sites-available:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName wsgihost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/documents

       Alias /images/ /var/www/html/documents/images/

      <Directory /var/www/html/documents/images>
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
      </Directory>

      WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/scripts/first.wsgi  

      <Directory /var/www/html/scripts>
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
      </Directory>    
  </VirtualHost>
```

Here's the simple HTML, that i am getting as output on the browser:

```
      <html>
         <head>
           <body>
                <img src="/images/pic1.jpg"> 
           </body>
         </head>
      </html
```

I am making some silly mistake out there, but couldn't find it, could somebody please help me out, thanks.

Comment: If you were using mod_wsgi-express as intended, you wouldn't be manually configuring Apache. Are you sure you are using mod_wsgi-express at all and not just using mod_wsgi module provided by the host operating system.

Comment: Just saw your comment, apologies for responding so late. I am using mod_wsgi-express, followed the README.rst file for installation. Totally honored by seeing you (and got really afraid here), got back to work immediately, luckily found that `--help` switch,  started `mod_wsgi-express start-server myapp --document-root /path` ...refreshed the browser...and image is there! Fear factor!! Is that a correct way to set document root?...as I am now seeing that document-root listed on httpd.conf in /tmp/mod_wsgi folder, which previously wasn't there.

Comment: Yes that is best way to introduce static files. Any static files under that document root will take precedence over any URLs handled by the web application. So they overlay. You can even put ``favicon.ico``, ``robots.txt`` files in there which would need to be at root of the site. If you only wanted to mount some files at a sub URL, such as at ``/static``, you could have used ``--url-alias /images/ /path/images/``.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. Things are working fine now. If you want and have time, you could post that as an answer, I'll accept it.